# How to get all possible characters pairs of given string?

Tags: java, string

I have one string "oracle". I want to get app possible pairs of characters. I tried doing it and was able to do it in `o(n*n)` . I am looking for more optimized solution. Can we solve it in less than `o(n*n)` ?

```
Input : oracle
Output : "or" "oa", "oc", "ol", "oe" , "ra", "rc", "rl", "re" , "ac", "al", "ae", "cl", "ce", "le"
```

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not possible, simply because the output size is based on `O(n*n)`. Depending on exact requirements it's either up to `n*(n-1)` or `n*(n-1)/2` (if we need to keep the order from the original word).

Comment: I was solving one problem and i need to get pairs of characters for given string and that string size is very big. So was getting time out error. Thanks Zbynek.

Answer (score -1):

```
    String string = "oracle";
    HashMap occurs = new HashMap();

    for(int i=0; i<string.length(); i++)
        occurs.put(""+string.charAt(i), new Boolean(true));

    for(char a='a'; a < 'z'; a++)
        if(occurs.get(""+a)!=null)
            for(char b=(char) (a+1); b<'z'; b++)
                if(occurs.get(""+b)!=null)
                    System.out.print(a+""+b+" ");
```

It is possible in linear time.

 First, you need a boolean array (! for constant look up times) of all characters in the alphabet and iterate over the string to check, which characters are contained. *(linear)*
Second, you need to iterate over all possible pairs of characters and check for both characters, if they were contained, so if the corresponding booleans are *true*. *(constant)*
I can provide some code, if required

Greets!

Comment: Thanks Syntac, as you said we need to iterate over all possible parts here. Wouldn't that need O(n *n) ? Correct me if i am wrong here.

Comment: No, you only iterate over each char of the string once. No nested loops or something. Ill write you some js-code. We just need in the second mart quadratic runtime, but not quadratic to n, but to the length of the alphabet, which is constant again.

Comment: How is a Javascript solution applicable to a Java question?

Comment: @JimGarrison Yes, you are right. But what shall I do? remove it? he asked for explanation. I could change it in pseudo-code or sit down and change to java, but is that really necessary?